# Standalone Health Checks

Tags: server, intervals, cloudflare, minimum, downtime

Minimum Interval - The lowest allowed interval between checks:
Pro: 60
Business: 15
Enterprise: 10

This is the interval in the Documentation. Is it in **seconds**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is in seconds. Just be careful if you're configuring that for multiple domains on the same server. We've mini-DDOSed ourselves after misconfiguring the health checks. Turns out that the more regions you have, the more checks happen from each region - these can be more frequent than the interval configured.

Check [this](https://blog.cloudflare.com/health-check-analytics-and-how-you-can-use-it/) out.